# How does Mai from the Pilaf gang become younger?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball, dragon-ball-super

This was Mai in Dragon Ball:

[image]

And this is Mai in Dragon Ball Super:

[image]

How does she become younger?

Comment: Somehow she looks to be around Future Trunks' age in his timeline, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Pilaf Gang gathered the Dragon Balls and wished for youth before the events of the *Battle of Gods Movie*. Though, it is never shown on screen, but it's mentioned in the movie and the series.

> ***Mai:*** Earlier, when we were finally about to get Shenlong to grant our wish, Pilaf-sama, you said "Make us young again!"
>   ***Pilaf:*** Y-Yeah, but... there's no point in dominating the world when we're old, if we're going to drop dead right away.
>   ***Mai:*** Maybe so, but we're too young like this!
>   ***Shū:*** It was a relief for me. My life has been greatly extended, in dog years.